# print with two for loops in python

Tags: python

I have a question about python.

I need to print two variables stored in a list.
example
list1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]

output print:
1a, 2b, 3c

Answer (score 1):

You want `zip`.

```
for i1, i2 in zip(list1, list2):
    print(i1 + i2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` and `.join()` to produce the desired output:

```py
list1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]

# Prints 1a, 2b, 3c
print(', '.join(''.join(item) for item in zip(list1, list2)))
```